# Non-singular derivative in $\mathbb{R}^n$ implies open image

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be of class $C^r$; assume $Df(\textbf{x})$ is non-singular for $\textbf{x}\in A$. Show that if $f$ is not one-to-one on $A$, the set $B=f(A)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The class $C^r$ appears only once in the problem statement, so we can only assume the weakest condition, that $r=1$. In this case $f$ is of class $C^1$. So the $n$ partial derivatives of $f$ exist and are continuous. The derivative of $f$ also exists, and is continuous.

To prove that $B$ is open, pick $\textbf{b}\in B$. We must show that some open ball $B(\textbf{b},\delta)$ is contained in $B$. We have $\textbf{b}=f(\textbf{a})$ for some $\textbf{a}\in A$. How to proceed from here?

Comment: Use the inverse function theorem/